# How do I change the evaluation of the expression in the conditional to check for a boolean in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, conditional-statements, coercion

I'm creating a coin flip game, and the very last step is to use a math methods to get a solid number on the coin flip. Then change the evaluation of the expression in the conditional so that it checks for a boolean. What are some ways I can achieve this? What am I doing wrong?

```js
var coinFlip = Math.random();
var choice = window.prompt("Select heads or tails");
if (coinFlip < 0.5) {
    choice === window.console.log("heads");
} else {
    choice === window.console.log("tails");
} if (choice === "heads" && coinFlip < 0.5) {
    window.alert("The flip was heads and you chose heads..you win!");
} else if (choice !== "heads" && coinFlip < 0.5) {
    window.alert(" The flip was heads and you chose tails...you lose!");
} else if (choice !== "tails" && coinFlip > 0.5) {
    window.alert("The flip was tails but you choose heads...you lose!");
} else if (choice === "tails" && coinFlip > 0.5) {
    window.alert("The flip was tails and you chose tails...you win!");  
}
coinFlip = Math.Round(Math.Random);
coinFlip = Boolean(choice);
```

**strong text**

Comment: what do you mean with solid number? please add an example of the wanted result.

Comment: I meant solid whole number.

Comment: What's the intent of this code? `choice === window.console.log("heads");` Did you mean to assign a value to `choice`? In that case you want `choice = "heads";`.

Comment: Btw, just as in real live you have a small but non-zero chance to get `coinFlip == 0.5` :-)

Answer (score 0):

You could round the random value with [`Math.round`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round).

```
Math.round(coinFlip);
```

```js
var coinFlip = Math.random();

console.log(Math.round(coinFlip));

var choice = window.prompt("Select heads or tails");
if (coinFlip < 0.5) {
    console.log("heads");
} else {
    console.log("tails");
}

if (choice === "heads" && coinFlip < 0.5) {
    window.alert("The flip was heads and you chose heads..you win!");
} else if (choice !== "heads" && coinFlip < 0.5) {
    window.alert(" The flip was heads and you chose tails...you lose!");
} else if (choice !== "tails" && coinFlip > 0.5) {
    window.alert("The flip was tails but you choose heads...you lose!");
} else if (choice === "tails" && coinFlip > 0.5) {
    window.alert("The flip was tails and you chose tails...you win!");  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about doing away with the numbers altogether? You don't need a "solid whole number", you need heads or tails.

`Math.random()` returns a real number between 0 and 1 — if you `Math.round()` that, you will get either `0` or `1` exactly.
Below, zero equates to heads and one equates to tails when the rounded number is used as an index into an array.

```js
const sides = [ "heads", "tails" ];

function play() {
    var choice = window.prompt("Select heads or tails");
    var flip = sides[ Math.round(Math.random()) ];
    console.log("flip was " + flip);
    if (choice === flip) {
        window.alert("You won with " + choice);
    }
    else {
        window.alert("You lost - your choice was " + choice +
                    " but the flip came up " + flip);
    }
}

play();
```